# SQL Workbench crashing after running a query (MySQL Workbench 8.0.32) M1

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

SQL Workbench immediately crashed after running a select query.[image]

Device: M1 2020 MBP 13"

Note: I am using the MySQL Workbench 8.0.32 version for Mac

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Answer (score 17):

Downgrading to **MySQL Workbench 8.0.31** solved it for me. Hope this bug gets fixed soon.

https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/